# What does std::execution::unseq offer over a for loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, c++17, vectorization

I would like to see an example of a for loop which can't be auto-vectorized but which could when rewritten using parallel STL.

Comment: See [std::execution::unsequenced_policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) _"...The execution policy type used as a unique type to disambiguate parallel algorithm overloading and indicate that a parallel algorithm's execution may be vectorized,_"...

Comment: That statement doesn't help me understand the difference. A for loop may be vectorized as well. Is it just documenting that vectorization may be expected? Can the compiler do something with that information that it couldn't do without it?

Comment: With `unseq`, the compiler is allowed to **assume** that vectorizing will not change the semantics rather than having to prove it by analyzing the loop body.

Comment: can you provide an example where it might have inferred different behavior?

Comment: Not so much "might have inferred different behavior" as "couldn't infer anything"; `std::execution::unseq` says "I promise that it's okay to vectorize this; if it screws up, I'll take responsibility".

Comment: @PeteBecker so can you provide an example where it makes a difference?

Comment: Execution policies are not enforced, they are merely suggestions on how the algorithm be executed. If not possible, they are just "ignored".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on algorithms' implementation that supports unseq policies: whether they use special compiler magic or not. Example:

```cpp
sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    sum += a[i];
```

Here we sum up into a variable that is common for all lanes of vectors. Compiler mightn't guess how to vectorize the code efficiently.

However, we can call a C++17 algorithm with `unseq` policy:

```cpp
sum = std::reduce(std::execution::unseq, a, a + n);
```

And it could be faster if implementation uses more complex logic to make compiler vectorize the code. For example, [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/pstl/unseq_backend_simd.h#L447). Here you can also find some more complex examples that can be vectorized efficiently than auto-vectorized for loop, e.g.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    if (pred(in[i]))
    {
        *out = in[i];
        ++out;
    }
}
```

comparing to

```cpp
std::copy_if(std::execution::unseq, in, in + n, out, [](auto val){return val > 0;});
```